# What is the use of open variables over public variables which are stored?

Tags: swift

I have checking out some code and I came across code that is marked as `open` for a variable and it is a stored property. What kind of use does `open` have over `public` in this case? This is some made up code:

```
open class God {
    open var hasSuperPowers = true
}

class HalfGod: God {
    override var hasSuperPowers = false
}
```

This does not compile: `Cannot override with a stored property 'hasSuperPowers'`. This is because the variable is stored.

My question is therefore: **What difference does it make when marking my stored property either `open` or `public`?** Can I do something with an `open` stored property, which I can not do with a `public` stored property?

I would expect `xCode` would give me warning that marking `hasSuperPowers` as `open` would have no effect and would falsely imply to other people that they can override this variable. Ofcourse, this only applies when someone can confirm me that `open` or `public` does not make any difference.

Edit: I got now three people showing me the difference between open and var. Does my question even get read? Again:

**What difference does it make when marking my stored property either `open` or `public`?** Again: **STORED PROPERTY**

Comment: @Sh_Khan can you point out the sentence that would help me finding the answer to my question in your provided link? I know the difference between `open` and `public`.

Comment: I think I have answered exactly your question. You can override stored property in another module only if it's public. I have shown what does it mean to override a stored property.

Comment: @Sulthan 'You can override stored property in another module only if it's public' What? Clearly we can not override stored properties. And only if it is public? I don't understand.

Comment: Clearly you *can* override stored properties. You cannot override them *with another stored property*. You can override a stored property only with a computed property.

Comment: @Sulthan Wow yes you are right :/ I feel dumb now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override a property but *not with a stored property*. When overriding properties, you have to use a computed property, e.g.:

A class with a stored property:

```
open class God {
   open var hasSuperPowers = true
}
```

The property can be overriden only with a computed property:

```
class HalfGod: God {
    override var hasSuperPowers: Bool {
        didSet {
            print("\(oldValue) -> \(hasSuperPowers)")
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
class HalfGod: God {
    var hasPowers: Bool = false

    override var hasSuperPowers: Bool {
        get {
           return hasPowers
        }
        set {
           hasPowers = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

You can override properties from other modules only if they are `open`. `public` properties cannot be overriden from other modules.

Answer (score 0):

From the link in the comment:

An open class is accessible and subclassable outside of the defining module. An open class member is accessible and overridable outside of the defining module.

A public class is accessible but not subclassable outside of the defining module. A public class member is accessible but not overridable outside of the defining module.

*What difference does it make when marking my stored property either open or public?*

- If its marked public, then you cannot override the member outside the defining module.

*Can I do something with an open stored property, which I can not do with a public stored property?*

- You can subclass it outside of the defining module.